# How to pass object dynamically to attribute in angular

Tags: angular

Html:

```
<coral-item *ngFor="let history of requestHistory" (click)="selectedHistory(history)"
            [title]="history+[selectedRequestType]+requestHistory">
            {{ history[selectedRequestType].Formula }}</coral-item>
```

where `selectedRequestType` is variable I want to pass dynamically but how it gets shown as:

```
[object Object]value[object Object],[object Object][object Object]
```

Comment: You are trying to print an object as string. You might want to check what those object contains and print the according key. Alternativaly, you could override the `toString` method of your object to return some actual values.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a Stackblitz and tell us which output you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following expression:
`[title]="history[selectedRequestType].requestHistory"`

Comment: What was the error? I use similar syntax for attribute binding without error... You could also bind it to a method like this : `[title]="getRequestHistory(history)"`